# RadioButtons, layout horizontal e vertical

Tags: android, radiobutton

Tenho um layout com 6 RadioButtons.

Eles ficam tanto na horizontal quanto na vertical.

Como posso resolver este problema? Já que utilizando 3 RadioGroups, eu não consigo desmarcar o radiobutton que estiver fora do grupo. Sendo assim, eu consigo marcar até 3 RadioButtons, mas deveria ser apenas um marcado.

Como resolver no layout ou programaticamente. Obrigado

Segue layout:

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup_map1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/branco"
                android:text="Case 1"
                android:textColor="@color/branco" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/branco"
                android:text="Case 2"
                android:textColor="@color/branco" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup_map2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/branco"
                android:text="Case 3"
                android:textColor="@color/branco" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/branco"
                android:text="Case 4"
                android:textColor="@color/branco" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup_map3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/branco"
                android:text="Case 5"
                android:textColor="@color/branco" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/branco"
                android:text="Case 6"
                android:textColor="@color/branco" />

        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Você pretende um Radiogroup com 6 RadioButtons dispostos em 3 linhas de 3? Se sim veja esta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2381560/2556111)

Comment: @ramaral seria isso, consegui utilizando vários groups, mas utilizando varios groups, não consigo deixar somente 1 radiobutton marcado, podendo estar até 3, preciso que somente 1 fique marcado. Vou ver a resposta

Comment: Você está fazendo da maneira mais difícil, basta usar os recursos de margens de cada radio Button e você consegue esse efeito ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte maneira o Layout:

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/rb_rua_movimentada"
                        android:textSize="13dp"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/rb_iluminacao"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/rb_comercio"
                        android:textSize="13dp"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/rb_assedio"
                        android:textSize="13dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/rb_posto_policial"
                        android:textSize="13dp"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/rb_porteiro"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RadioGroup>
```

No código:

implementado `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`

> ```
> onCreate
> ```

```
   rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup_Map1);

rb_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
rb_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
rb_3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
rb_4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
rb_5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
rb_6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Método para alterar o setChecked:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
            case R.id.rb_1:
                rb_1.setChecked(true);
                rb_2.setChecked(false);
                rb_6.setChecked(false);
                rb_4.setChecked(false);
                rb_3.setChecked(false);
                rb_5.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.rb_2:
                rb_1.setChecked(false);
                rb_2.setChecked(true);
                rb_6.setChecked(false);
                rb_4.setChecked(false);
                rb_3.setChecked(false);
                rb_5.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.rb_3:
                rb_1.setChecked(false);
                rb_2.setChecked(false);
                rb_6.setChecked(false);
                rb_4.setChecked(false);
                rb_3.setChecked(true);
                rb_5.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.rb_4:
                rb_1.setChecked(false);
                rb_2.setChecked(false);
                rb_6.setChecked(false);
                rb_4.setChecked(true);
                rb_3.setChecked(false);
                rb_5.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.rb_5:
                rb_1.setChecked(false);
                rb_2.setChecked(false);
                rb_6.setChecked(false);
                rb_4.setChecked(false);
                rb_3.setChecked(false);
                rb_5.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case R.id.rb_6:
                rb_1.setChecked(false);
                rb_2.setChecked(false);
                rb_6.setChecked(true);
                rb_4.setChecked(false);
                rb_3.setChecked(false);
                rb_5.setChecked(false);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque todos os 6 dentro de um único radiogroup e no xml aponte android:orientation="horizontal". Isso é essencial. A separação deles se fará com a distância ou margem entre eles,de modo que caiba apenas dois em cada "linha" da interface.

Answer (score -1):

Você tem que deixar todos os RadioButtons dentro de um único RadioGroup e usar um ViewGroup (RelativeLayout, por exemplo) para orgarnizar os RadioButtons da forma que você quiser.

```
Ficaria algo assim:
<RadioGroup>
   <RelativeLayout>
       <RadioButton />
       <RadioButton />
       <RadioButton />
       <RadioButton />
       <RadioButton />
       <RadioButton />
   </RelativeLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Tem a certeza que isso funciona?

Comment: Tem razão, não funciona. Apesar do RadioGroup ser uma subclasse de um LinearLayout, o comportamento dos RadioButtons só funciona quando são filhos diretos do RadioGroup. Outra alternativa que eu posso pensar é esquecer o RadioGroup e tratar a marcação/desmarcação dos RadioButtons no código mesmo. Não é tão complicado de fazer.

Comment: Experimente essa library: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4992

Comment: O layout com linear layout, funciona. Vou testar aqui a codificação, na activity e coloco. Caso funcione